# Access to Medical ID

Tags: ios, iphone, health.app

I read about Medical ID in the Health app on my iPhone 5S, and have created one.

The app talks about "tapping Emergency" when locked to access.

Where is this "Emergency"?

Is there any way of entering details from my Mac.
I already have these in text files, and don't want to retype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the Emergency functionality by:

1. Wake your phone (press the power or home buttons)
2. Slide to unlock
3. On the unlock (keypad) screen, tap the "Emergency" button at the bottom left of the screen

The Emergency button should yield another keypad with the button labeled "Medical ID" in the bottom left.